# count votes for specific reply

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that keeps record of vote

Condition

1. Reply can have many votes;
2. User can vote once to specific reply id.

   table: `reply_vote`

   ```
       +----+-------------+-------------+   
       | id |   reply_id  | userID      | 
       +----+-------------+----+--------+   
       | 1  | 23          | 21          | 
       | 3  | 33          | 21          | 
       | 4  | 23          | 25          | 
       | 5  | 23          | 12          |
   ```

I want to display the total votes on each reply

e.g

> reply_id 23 has 3 votes with userid (21,25,12)
>
> reply_id 33 has 1 vote with userid (21)

I don't want to fetch all data using while loop in php

up till now I have used below query but it is displaying all the votes on the page which is not what is required

```
SELECT
  reply.id,
  reply.reply,
  COUNT(reply_vote.id) AS likes
FROM reply
  LEFT JOIN reply_vote ON reply_vote.reply_id = reply.id
GROUP BY reply.id
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: i used below code to fetch data from the query i wrote above, it displays all the data on each reply in output




**while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
 {   echo '<h3>'.$row["reply"].'</h3>';  
     // echo '<a href="index.php?type=article&id='.$row["id"].'">Like</a>';  
      echo '<p>'.$row["likes"].' People like this</p>';} **

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: i want create vote count that display eachreply  id with its vote like facebook likes

Comment: "I want to display the total votes on each reply" - IMHO your query is doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT reply.id, reply.reply, 
    COUNT(reply_vote.id) as likes
    FROM reply 
    INNER JOIN reply_vote ON reply_vote.reply_id = reply.id 
    GROUP BY reply_vote.reply_id
```